# Keylistener is "laggy". Stops working then works again after about 5 seconds

Tags: java, keylistener

Original Question:

I have a question about Keylisteners. I'm trying to make a simple 2D shooter game for my class. The problem doesn't seem to be in the code as the character's movement works fine, but keylistener suddenly stops working and then works again after 5 seconds. But during those 5 seconds, keylistener doesn't register anything. I've checked this by printing out my set of pressed keys and during the "lag time" nothing I press registers. How can I fix this? Below is my code for the game class and character movement.

Summary of What I Tried/Changed:

I have reformatted the block code as well as tried to put j1.addKeyListener(this) into main as user7185318 suggested. However, I encountered an error saying "cannot use this in a static context." I tried rephrasing the problem (below) to be more specific. To Lew Block, could you show me how to run GUI on EDT?

Rephrased Problem Description:

My character is a sprite BufferedImage that I drew. The BufferedImage's location is set to that of a Rectangle that is essentially a hit box for the character. I used the affineTransform class to allow the BufferedImage to spin. I noticed that the problem usually comes with repressing the movement keys. (W = up, S = down, etc...) The first time I press these keys, the character moves smoothly and spins as it is supposed to. However, after I let go of the keys and press the keys again, the character doesn't respond anymore. This failure of response doesn't happen every time. Sometimes it works, other times it doesn't.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends GameDriverV2 implements KeyListener{

    //Background Rectangle
    Rectangle bg = new Rectangle(0,0,1200,700);

    //Main Player
    Player p1 = new Player(this.addImage("character.png"));
    Rectangle p1Follow = new Rectangle(100, 300, 55, 55);
    double playerTurnAngle = 0.0;
    boolean playerTurnR = false, playerTurnL = false;
    int playerDx, playerDy;
    int timer;

    //set of pressed keys
    private final Set<Character> pressed = new HashSet<Character>();

    public Game(){
        this.addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame j1 = new JFrame();
        j1.setSize(1200,700);
        j1.setTitle("Game"); //Change when know the name of the game
        j1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        j1.add(new Game());
        j1.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics2D win){
        //draw and set color for background 
        win.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        win.fill(bg);
        //setting change in angle by KeyListenerBelow
        if(playerTurnR){
            playerTurnAngle += Math.PI/45;
        }else if(playerTurnL){
            playerTurnAngle -= Math.PI/45;
        }
        p1.moveAndDrawNorm(win, p1Follow);
        p1.setPlayerTurnAngle(playerTurnAngle);
        p1Follow.translate(playerDx, playerDy);
    }


    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pressed.add(e.getKeyChar());
        if (pressed.size() > 1) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
                playerTurnR = true;             
            }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){       
                playerTurnL = true;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A){
                playerDx = -3;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D){
                playerDx = 3;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W){
                playerDy = -3;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S){
                playerDy = 3;
            }
        }else{
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
                playerTurnR = true;             
            }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){       
                playerTurnL = true;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A){
                playerDx = -3;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D){
                playerDx = 3;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W){
                playerDy = -3;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S){
                playerDy = 3;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pressed.remove(e.getKeyChar());
        if (pressed.size() > 1) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
                playerTurnR = false;                
            }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){       
                playerTurnL = false;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A){
                playerDx = 0;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D){
                playerDx = 0;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W){
                playerDy = 0;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S){
                playerDy = 0;
            }
        }else{
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
                playerTurnR = false;                
            }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){       
                playerTurnL = false;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A){
                playerDx = 0;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D){
                playerDx = 0;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W){
                playerDy = 0;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S){
                playerDy = 0;
            }
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you fix the formatting (e.g. the last `}` or the comment before the code block) and post the complete code of the Game class? For example I can't see the defition of the class `public class Game...` etc.

Comment: Please update your question with a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces the issue.

Comment: Maybe if you run the GUI on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) as you ought? Not doing so often leads to very weird behavior similar to what you describe. Also, `System.out.println` has no business in a GUI, nor as a debugging​ aid. Use a logger!

Comment: **Type this in your main method : `j1.addKeyListener(this);` and remove in Game constructor  `this.addKeyListener(this)` . This may be the solution, since youre not applying the KeyListener to a JFrame, instead of that, to your class, which makes absolutely no sense.**

Comment: I have edited my post (tried to rephrase problem) as well as addressed some of the comments as best I can. For user7185318, I tried adding j1.addKeyListener(this) into my main method and I was met with a "cannot use this in a static context error." For Lew Bloch, I haven't learned what a GUI and EDT is yet, and thus I don't know how to run a GUI on EDT. Can you redirect me or show me an example for that? Thanks. For Radiodef, I haven't been able to reproduce the error. I've written games in this format before and never had this problem (but they were much simpler games eg. pong, breakout).

Comment: Hello all who commented. I consulted my teacher about this problem, and after logging and printing out my set, we found that the KeyListener just completely stops to listen after a certain period of time. I am coding on a Macbook Pro (using Eclipse), and I was wondering if that could be the problem? Another possibility is that the KeyListener is losing focus, but I don't know how to reset the focus. When I used j1.requestFocusInWindow() the boolean returned was false. Could someone direct me? Thank you all for your help.